# Hyperledger Fabric: Can transaction proposal be forwarded to the endorsing peer in another node by using fabric-python-sdk?

Tags: hyperledger-fabric

I have set up the Hyperledger-fabric network(v.1.4.7) as follows:

- Node1 - peer0.org1.example.com (10.10.10.1)
- Node2 - peer0.org2.example.com (10.10.10.2)
- Node3 - peer0.org3.example.com (10.10.10.3)

And I am trying to send a transaction using fabric-sdk-py and grpc.

[fabric network setting image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yGmdQ.png)

But I got this error.

```
ERROR:grpc._server:Exception calling application: ['ENDORSEMENT_POLICY_FAILURE']
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/ben/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/grpc/_server.py", line 435, in _call_behavior
    response_or_iterator = behavior(argument, context)
  File "grpclb_server.py", line 163, in Execute
    wait_for_event=True, # for being sure chaincode invocation has been commited in the ledger, default is on tx event
  File "/home/ben/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/nest_asyncio.py", line 95, in run_until_complete
    return f.result()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/asyncio/tasks.py", line 180, in _step
    result = coro.send(None)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/fabric_sdk_py-0.9.0-py3.6.egg/hfc/fabric/client.py", line 1730, in chaincode_invoke
    raise Exception(statuses)
Exception: ['ENDORSEMENT_POLICY_FAILURE']
ERROR:grpc._server:Exception calling application: ['ENDORSEMENT_POLICY_FAILURE']ERROR:grpc._server:Exception calling application: ['ENDORSEMENT_POLICY_FAILURE']
```

- `network.json` file

```
    "peers": {
        "peer0.org1.example.com": {
            "url": "peer0.org1.example.com:7051",
            "eventUrl": "peer0.org1.example.com:7053",
            "grpcOptions": {
                "grpc.ssl_target_name_override": "peer0.org1.example.com",
                "grpc-max-send-message-length": 15
            }
        },
        "peer0.org2.example.com": {
            "url": "peer0.org2.example.com:7051",
            "eventUrl": "peer0.org2.example.com:7053",
            "grpcOptions": {
                "grpc.ssl_target_name_override": "peer0.org2.example.com",
                "grpc-max-send-message-length": 15
            }
        },
        "peer0.org3.example.com": {
            "url": "peer0.org3.example.com:7051",
            "eventUrl": "peer0.org3.example.com:7053",
            "grpcOptions": {
                "grpc.ssl_target_name_override": "peer0.org3.example.com",
                "grpc-max-send-message-length": 15
            }
```

- grpc_server.py

```
class GrpclbServicer(grpclb_pb2_grpc.GrpclbServicer):
    def Execute(self, request, context):
        orgs = ['org1.example.com','org2.example.com','org3.example.com']

        # The response should be true if succeed
        for org in orgs:
            org_admin = cli.get_user(org_name=org, name='Admin')
            print(org_admin)
            response = loop.run_until_complete(cli.chaincode_invoke(
                                requestor=org_admin,
                                channel_name=request.channelName, # "mychannel"
                                peers=['peer0.'+org],
                                fcn=request.functionName, # "createCar"
                                args=request.args, 
                                cc_name=request.chaincodeName, # "fabcar"
                                transient_map=None, # optional, for private data
                                wait_for_event=True, # for being sure chaincode invocation has been commited in the ledger, default is on tx event
...
def serve():
    server = grpc.server(futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=100))
    grpclb_pb2_grpc.add_GrpclbServicer_to_server(
        GrpclbServicer(), server)
    server.add_insecure_port('[::]:50051')
    server.start()
    server.wait_for_termination()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    logging.basicConfig()
    serve()
```

is it possible to send tx proposal to endorsing peer in another node?
If possible, what should be modified? (network.json or grpc_server.py ?...)

Comment: install fabric CA first. https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-2.2/deployment_guide_overview.html

Comment: @NguyenTienHuy I already installed fabric-ca and my fabric version is v1.4.7...

Comment: certs for auth in network.json???

Comment: @NguyenTienHuy  Should I put the certs information even if I don't use CA and generate msp information through Configtxgen?